# Error in Python Mechanize - "mechanize._mechanize.BrowserStateError: not viewing HTML"

Tags: python, mechanize

```
for link in br.links(url_regex="inquiry-results.jsp"):
    cb[link.url] = link

for page_link in cb.values():               
   for link in br.links(url_regex="inquiryDetail.jis"): 
            ....................
      url = link.absolute_url
      br.follow_link(link)
            ......................
   br.follow_link(page_link)
```

This is my code. Basically, it extracts page links [Link of page 1,2,3,4,5...] and data links from particular page. Then it goes in each data link and extracts some data and when done it moves to the next page. But I always get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python27\test.py", line 95, in <module>
    for link in br.links(url_regex="inquiryDetail.jis"):
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\mechanize\_mechanize.py", line 405, in links
mechanize._mechanize.BrowserStateError: not viewing HTML
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be related to a check to see if the response is valid HTML:

http://github.com/jjlee/mechanize/blob/master/mechanize/_mechanize.py#L440

Perhaps the response you get it XHTML, or has invalid headers? There may be some way to override the `is_html` attribute (like [here](http://hackmap.blogspot.com/2008/10/twill-with-xhtml-not-viewing-html.html)).

Comment: Has someone found how this twill function translates into Mechanize?

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to the link posted by loevborg, I've been using this:

```
br.open('http://example.com')
br._factory.is_html = True
```

Now `br.viewing_html()` will evaluate to True

Answer (score 0):

Introduce your app as a browser before br.open might help this:

```
br.addheaders = [('User-agent','Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/45.0.2454101')]
```